# How to convert a tuple type with optional elements to required elements

Tags: typescript, types

The `createActivity` function will be called after the form checks out, so the `dateRange` field must have a value, and I need to convert the optional element in the `dateRange` to the required element type.

```
type BaseActivityFormFields = {
    activityName: string;
    dateRange: [Date?, Date?];
};

type CreateActivityParams = {
    activityName: string;
    startTime: number;
    endTime: number;
}

function createActivity(formFields: BaseActivityFormFields) {
    const params: CreateActivityParams = {
        activityName: formFields.activityName,
        startTime: formFields.dateRange[0].getTime(),
        endTime: formFields.dateRange[1].getTime(),
    };
    // Call API
}
```

I need to covert the `BaseActivityFormFields` to below:

```
type BaseActivityFormFieldsValidated = {
    activityName: string;
    dateRange: [Date, Date];
};

// Something like this:
// type BaseActivityFormFieldsValidated = SomeMagicUtilityType<BaseActivityFormFields>;

function createActivity(formFields: BaseActivityFormFieldsValidated) {
    const params: CreateActivityParams = {
        activityName: formFields.activityName,
        startTime: formFields.dateRange[0].getTime(),
        endTime: formFields.dateRange[1].getTime(),
    };
    // Call API
}
```

I don't want to use [non-null-assertion-operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) like this:

```
formFields.dateRange[0]!.getTime()
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgQQMbAJYDcOgGID2ATgLZ4YQA2AJglALxQDeAUFO1HOtriAHJwSEAFxQEwIhgB2AcwDcbDtTjAIAJTiyRUANoARFRAD8AGigHVRgLoKAvgpahIUAMJEIhtJhygACnCJBOkZWDk5uH35BbXFJWQUw8QDgABUMIVEpAFcSACMIIgSOCClqNIyobLyCuxYWADMsqW4CKShUd08I3gAKeuIyChoEUXgkLx58AfIqWgBKZkV2VFbxKDAAoNE3D1UJyP9AkmDFsLCub14BCv7SGeGAOgvJqKETJbOkolT07VvB2YIB7KVQaLQ6AAMVgeMggPyEPTm7zOxVK5T+0yGtGBhjBsJ0AEZobD4RBEciOPYPgB6amuOCUShQZC+ACSLFsdSAA)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make all elements of tupe non-optional - [Required](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype).

```js
type BaseActivityFormFields = {
    activityName: string;
    dateRange: [Date?, Date?];
};

type CreateActivityParams = {
    activityName: string;
    startTime: number;
    endTime: number;
}

type MakeRequired<
    T extends BaseActivityFormFields,
    Prop extends keyof T> =
    Omit<T, Prop> & Record<Prop, Required<T[Prop]>>

function createActivity(formFields: MakeRequired<BaseActivityFormFields, 'dateRange'>) {
    const x = formFields.dateRange[0]
    const params: CreateActivityParams = {
        activityName: formFields.activityName,
        startTime: formFields.dateRange[0].getTime(),
        endTime: formFields.dateRange[1].getTime(),
    };
    // Call API
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAQghgZwgQQMbAJYDcOgGID2ATgLZ4YQA2AJglALxQDeAUFO1HOtriAHJwSEAFxQEwIhgB2AcwDcbDtTjAIAJTiyRUANoARFRAD8AGigHVRgLoKAvgpahIUAMJEIhtJhygACnCJBOkZWDk5uH35BbXFJWQUw8QDgABUMIVEpAFcSACMIIgSOCClqNIyobLyCuxZHcGgAWTgAa3UIAEcsjHdqAB4UqAgAD1VSungkLx58YjIKGgQzXyICMCHRktooNpACADMoFIA%20BigAeRJcAeXVsFOAMig1CFRifpW1sxeunoh%20lI6T5gKzHY51fZZKTcAhSKCodyeCK8AAU%20zm5CotFEzTaP26vT6kxQyNmpExizMAHJlKoNFoqccAJTMRTsN5ScRQYZndHkha0AB0tPUmhkEB0AAYrGz4bCuWAAkFRG4PKpppF-IESMFWWEwlxvLwBBU%20fMsQhBYaZlEhCZZYlgMlytozRShSL6eKpVZBeLUukICimfb9cVSi7RG6BZbPWKJQBGX3%20l3B0MceyygD0WdccEolCgyF8AEkWLY6kA)

`MakeRequired` accepts two arguments:

- first is the objects, in our case BaseActivityFormFields
- second is the name of property you want to make a required